# what's the random byte mentioned in linux `shuf` --random-source?

Tags: linux, shuffle, random-seed

I'm trying to prepare a few shuffled files with Linux `shuf` command, however, through `shuf --help`, it doesn't provide any "seed" option. I wonder if there is any workaround? Thanks!

Updates:

thanks to the remind in the comments, I realize (1) `shuf FILE` produce different result each time; and (2) when `--random-source` are same, the produced results are same, so I guess can be used to make the shuffling procedure replicatable?

Then just out of curiosity: for long I thought randomness is controlled by the random seed, but as the `man` said, `--random-source` specify where to read the "random bytes". I wonder how is this random bytes related to the random seed?

Comment: Doesn't `--random-source` ring a bell? Why do you need to provide a seed to shuf? Do you intent to have _reproducible_ random order of lines in files?

Comment: thanks! I saw it describes `--random-source` as "get random bytes from FILE", but not sure what does the "random bytes" mean? - and I was trying to send a seed since I wanna shuffle a file differently, and I assume if no seed is provided, `shuf` will use a default internal seed, which will then shuffle the file in the same way each time?

Comment: How did you arrive at that conclusion? Did you test that assumption?

Comment: ah my bad, you r right...keep doing `shuf FILE` produces different results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if there is any workaround?

There is `--random-source` option.

> I guess can be used to make the shuffling procedure replicatable?

This is what `--random-source` is for.

> how is this random bytes related to the random seed?

It is **the source** of random bytes.

GNU `shuf` has an optimized as much as possible algorithm and that algorithm strongly depends on other options. In the most simplistic and crude oversimplification, you just choose a random number from `1` to the count of lines in the file and print the line with that number. Then repeat and choose a another number without repeats.

Browsing [GNU shuf.c sources](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/shuf.c#L539) I see the number generation is in [shuf/randint.c randint_genmax()](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/gl/lib/randint.c#L141).

Basically I believe you are confusing algorithms. Indeed [pseudorandom number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator) use a seed. However `shuf` is intended to work with `/dev/urandom` - a special file where the kernel itself [keeps a global seed](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/char/random.c#L451). And `shuf` is intended to work with **any** random number generation method. So `shuf` instead of requiring a seed for a specific random number generation method, it requires a stream which provides random bytes when reading from it.

Comment: Thanks! So I guess the FILE passed to `--random-source` is basically a replacement of `/dev/urandom` (which is the default "source of random bytes")?

Comment: `is basically a replacement of` yes